# POST data to a JSON REST API using request-promise of node

Tags: php, node.js, request, node-request

I am facing problem to get `$_POST` data in `PHP` file. As my request is sending post variable.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://localhost/orangehrm_live/capacity-dashboard/getAllDetailsCapacity.php',
    headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'Content-Length': dataString.length
     },
    body: {
        some: 'payload'
    },
    json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
};

rp(options)
    .then(function (repos) {
        console.log('User has %d repos', repos.length);
        if (repos) {
            res.send(repos);
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
```

My PHP file is containing following code.

```
<?php
class getAllDetailsCapacity{
    public function getChartRawData(){
        //$data = array('message' => 'HeLLO');


        $json = json_encode($_POST);
        print_r($json);
    }

}

function node_dispatch() {
        $obj=new getAllDetailsCapacity();
        if(isset($_POST)) {
            $obj->getChartRawData();
        }
        else {
            echo "You are in Admin Mode. Switch back to normal mode to serve your node app.";
        }
}

node_dispatch();
?>
```

It is showing else statement as its not getting post value in body of request promise of node function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_POST receives the post body when it contains key-value pairs.
You need to POST to php with the values you want url-encoded in the body.

The HTTP request could look like this:

```
POST /path/to/file.php HTTP/1.1
...
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

foo=bar&bar+baz=foo
```

Comment: please see my edited code in question as i have added headers but still post data is not coming

Answer (score 0):

Just add in headers and add form parameter instead of body . Your data get posted to PHP file.

```
headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        form: {
            some: dataString // Will be urlencoded
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The `content-type` header tells the library how to transform your javascript object into something the server is expecting. It also tells the server the format of the data coming from the client.

When you send the content-type header `application/json` the library converts your request to JSON. This will transform the body into the following: `{"some":"payload"}`.

When you send the content-type header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`the body is transformed into this: `some=payload`.